# How to set a 'Token xxxxxxxxxx' for 'Authorization' in HTTP header in URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

The backend APIs I'm working with require a token to be sent with every request against the HTTP header key `Authorization`  in this format - `Token xxxxxxxxxx`.

Right now, I'm doing the following.

```
var getRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
getRequest.addValue("Token xxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

This works sometimes and some other times, the header field `Authorization` is stripped when the request is sent out. I checked this using Charles proxy.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411532-httpadditionalheaders?language=objc) states the following.

> An NSURLSession object is designed to handle various aspects of the
>   HTTP protocol for you. As a result, you should not modify the
>   following headers: Authorization, Connection, Host, WWW-Authenticate

As a solution to this, many suggest using the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method for URLSession.

Here, you need to pass a `URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition` instance to tell how you want to respond to the challenge and a `URLCredential` instance to pass the credentials to respond to the authenticate challenge.

I do not know how to and if I can create a `URLCredential` instance that will add `Token xxxxxxxx` for the header field `Authorization`.

Can somebody more knowledgeable please help me how to go about solving this?

PS - All code mentioned in this question is in Swift 3.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920302/nsurlsession-with-token-authentication) asks something similar to what I have. But, the answers given there don't work for me. And, some of the questions asked under the questions regarding Apple not allowing headers for `Authorization` to be added have gone unanswered.

Edit:

Posting relevant code.

```
var getRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
getRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
getRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
getRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let token = DataProvider.sharedInstance.token
getRequest.addValue("Token \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let getTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: getRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            print("--------GET REQUEST RESPONSE START--------")
            print("CODE: \((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0)")
            print("Response Data:")
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            print("--------GET REQUEST RESPONSE END--------")
        }
}
getTask.resume()
```

Here, I can confirm that the header field for 'Authorization' is getting added to the request's header dictionary.

But, when I check what request hits the server, the header field for 'Authorization' is missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: `request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)` works reliable in my experience. I suspect your code is not called for the request in "problem situations". Please post more relevant code to figure this out.

Comment: @shallowThought I have added relevant code. Please see if you can find something wrong in what I did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this exact same issue and discovered that my lack of a trailing slash, `/`, was the problem.

The server was sending back a `301 Redirect` response. `URLSession` automatically follows the redirect, but will also drop the `Authorization` header. This is likely due to `Authorization`'s "special status". According to `URLSessionConfiguration`'s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411532-httpadditionalheaders):

> An URLSession object is designed to handle various aspects of the HTTP protocol for you. As a result, you should not modify the following headers:
>
> - Authorization
> - Connection
> - Host
> - WWW-Authenticate

If the `Authorization` header is required, implement `urlSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)` from `URLSessionTaskDelegate`. That method is passed the new request on redirect, allowing you to add back the header.

e.g.

```
class APIClient: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    let session: URLSession!
    initializeSession() {
        // Create a new session with APIClient as the delegate
        session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                             delegate: self,
                             delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    // Perform the request
    func fetchRecords(handler: () => void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee/records")!)
        request.setValue(retrieveToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: handler).resume()
    }

    // Implement URLSessionTaskDelegate's HTTP Redirection method
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        // Create a mutable copy of the new request, add the header, call completionHandler
        var newRequest = request
        newRequest.addValue(retrieveToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        completionHandler(newRequest)
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE!**

It's a bad idea to blindly trust a redirect. You should ensure that the URL you're being redirected to is the same domain as the original request. I've left that out of my code example for brevity.

Comment: Life saver... I had ran into this before, but you helped me remember.